# Is there a way to check a Magento 2.1.x DB health?

Tags: database, magento-2.1

I have a server that is running a soon to be production site, and a dev site. The Dev site is a complete copy from production (db & files). The only things changed for the Dev was The DB name itself, the UID/PSW used to connect to the database, and the URLs within the database for the dev site.

However, I was installing an extension on both sites, and I started to get unexpected errors on the production site, that I didn't get on the Dev site.

Specifically errors stemming from the URI class.

To clarify, I installed the plugin on the Dev site, had a minor issue, and the developer of that extension patched the problem (a slight incompatibility with our theme).  I then, proceeded to replicate the installation and all steps in the production environment, and suddenly I was getting a URI class error

> (Expecting a string or a URI object, received
>   "Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager), and then a (Object
>   DOMDocument should be created) error.

I just want to check my tables for health and consistency to make sure nothing is slowly going wrong with them, but I'm not sure if there is a recommended check path for Magento 2.1+ ?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to run the compiler on your production site. `magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: Does the dev site run in developer mode vs the production site in production mode? I currently don't believe the DB is the cause.

Comment: The "production" site isn't yet live (about another week or so), so both are running in Developer mode.